# Yii 2 wrong Routing?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I'm facing a problem but I don't know what may cause this.
When routing to some actions, for example when I click a button with the following code piece ..

```
 Html::a('<button class="pull-right btn btn-info btn-lg"><span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-th-large" ></span></button>',['user/create'],
['type'=>'button','align'=>'right']);
```

.. it routes to the default controller like the homepage!
Other buttons are routing right.
Any one can help what may cause wrong routing or wrong request?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try `['/user/create']` instead of `['user/create']`.

---

*Edit:*
Should the URL be routed? If not, try to use `user/create`.
There are different ways you can use the URL parameter: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to%28%29-detail

Comment: Thanks for replying but it still doesn't work . I'm facing this problem also when searching on grids it routes to the default .What may be the reason ?

Comment: What response do you get when you click on that link you mentioned above?
Maybe you can have a look into your network flow which response status is returned to you. Perhaps the call is redirected?

Comment: when i look at network traffic i see a wrong response "homepage response " but no errors .something in my debugger called _crsf holds the same urls which have the wrong response do have any idea what is this and what is it doing to my requests ??

Comment: I think you have a problem with your CSRF validation and therefore you will be redirected all the time.